# Equivalence of matrices and operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, quantum-information

I'm super new to studying functional analysis and I'm currently reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.7188.pdf (The Functional Analysis of Quantum Information Theory based on lectures  by Paulsen, Pisier, and Winter).  Anyway, it is claimed that

$$M_n(B(H)) \cong B(H^{(n)})$$
where 
$$H^{(n)} = H \oplus \cdots \oplus H$$

but I'm not quite sure how to make this identification, although it feels natural.

My attempt:

$M_1(B(H))\cong B(H)$ seems obvious since if we have an element of $B(H)$, call it $T$, then we can put $T$ in a matrix $[T]$ and so consider it an element of $M_1(B(H))$.

If I consider $M_2(B(H))\cong B(H^{(2)})$ it is not clear to me what the map is that connects these spaces (but I figure if I can understand this example then the general one follows).

I think, for starters, I should have a clear idea of what elements of $B(H^{(2)})$ are (and elements of $M_2(B(H))$ seem pretty clear).

Here's my take:  If $T\in B(H^{(2)})$ then it is bounded and operates on elements of $H^{(2)}$. Elements of $H^{(2)}$ look like $h=h_1\oplus h_2$ where $h_j \in H$ for $j=1,2$.

A "natural" way for an operator to act on something like $h$ is for us to define how it acts in each component... so presumably $T = T_1\oplus T_1$ and each $T_i$ is bounded since $T$ is. ... and we define 
$$Th = (T_1\oplus T_2)(h_1\oplus h_2) = (T_1h_1\oplus T_2h_2)$$

So my gut feeling is that this looks like:

$$Th = \begin{pmatrix} T_1&0\\0&T_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} h_1\\h_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} T_1h_1\\T_2h_2 \end{pmatrix}  $$

I don't actually know what $T_1\oplus T_2$ (or $T$) should look like, this just feels right.....

But... if this is the case, then I guess the isomorphism that helps me identify the spaces is a map which decomposes $T$ into its components then sends those to the appropriate diagonal matrix... yet this doesn't feel right because $M_2(B(H))$ should consist of more than just diagonal elements.

Thank you for reading.... I wrote out all my thoughts just to illustrate I've at least tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $M_n(B(H)) \cong B(H^n)$. So you sould indeed prove that there are more than just diagonal operators in $B(H^n)$. You can prove that the following map is an isomorphism of $C^*$-algebras:
$$
 \phi \colon M_n(B(H)) \to B(H^n),
$$
where 
$$
 \phi \big ( (T_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n \big)(\xi) = \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{k=1}^n T_{1k} \xi_k \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{k=1}^n T_{nk} \xi_k \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Here $\xi \in H^n$ has the form $\xi_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus \xi_n$. Note that $\phi$ lets the matrix $  (T_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n $  act on $\xi$ just as you would expect it, namely by matrix-multiplication.

Comment: I see.... (I'm going to use the case when $n=2$ to see if I understand).  So an element in $M_2(B(H))$ looks like $\begin{pmatrix} T_{1,1}&T_{1,2}\\T_{2,1}&T_{2,2} \end{pmatrix}$ with each $T_{i,j} \in B(H)$ this is where I was previously in my understanding.  

Now let me see if my intuition serves me correctly... Since $B(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is basically just matrices acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I should try to assume that $B(H^n)$ is no different.... essentially.

Comment: An element of $H^n$ is as you described and so we want something like $\begin{pmatrix} T_{1,1}&T_{1,2}\\T_{2,1}&T_{2,2} \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} \eta_1\\ \eta_2 \end{pmatrix}$ then the result is in $H^2$, moreover it is bounded because the $T_{i,j}$ are.

Comment: So this leads to my final question:  

It seems these spaces are the same thing (as isomorphism should show), but they seem identical.  Isn't it fair to define matrix-vector multiplication between $M_2(B(H))$ and $H^2$ as shown above without mention of $B(H^2)$?  

It seems like $\phi$ is nothing more than the statement "Matrix vector multiplication makes an identification between these spaces."

Answer (score 0):

To do this exercise, you should make sure you understand the case where $H=\mathbb C$, i.e. 
$$
M_n(\mathbb C)=M_n(B(\mathbb C))\simeq B(\mathbb C^n). 
$$
If you are able to do this carefully, replacing $\mathbb C$ with $H$ should not be hard.